# Evernote PHP sdk integration with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, header, evernote

I am using this documentation to set up Evernote cloud sdk php into Symfony2 :
https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/blob/master/documentation/Getting_Started.md

As they say, I installed it first with composer.
Then I am using this code

```
$sandbox = true;

$oauth_handler = new \Evernote\Auth\OauthHandler($sandbox);

$key      = '%key%';
$secret   = '%secret%';
$callback = 'http://host/pathto/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/sample/oauth/index.php';

$oauth_data  = $oauth_handler->authorize($key, $secret, $callback);

echo "\nOauth Token : " . $oauth_data['oauth_token'];
```

I changed the parameters with mine, but the problem is inside Evernote\Auth\OauthHandler :
https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Evernote/Auth/OauthHandler.php

The lib is using the function header(location: ...);
And the function is not executing.
I guess Symfony2 is not allowing the usage of this function.

Is there a way to force it ?
Or how can I change it in a good way (and to be able to push on my git repository) ?

Thanks,

Comment: are you going through the OAuth process? $oauth_data should contain a temporary OAuth token which you need to use to redirect the user to authorize your application.  You will then get a callback at the URL specified in $callback with the oauth_verifier command which you need to exchange via another call to get an access token which you can user to access the API.  More detailed info here [link](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php) If you're just getting started you may just want to use a developer token [link](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/dev_tokens.php)

Comment: Hi. My guess is that some headers are already sent by Symfony in some way, preventing the redirection to happen. (Just a guess). I don't have time to check it right now but I'll take a look asap and try to find a solution.

Comment: I am not seeting my own Oauth process, I am using authorize() Evernote method that is going through OAuth process.
Thanks for the link I will check that.

Yes Laurent you're right, thanks please let me know